# full scale output of a 4-bit DAC

Tags: dac

Find the full scale output of a 4-bit DAC produces an output of 0.1v for a digital input 0001

I am trying to learn digital circuits. While trying to do so I got stuck in this question.

Edit: Thanks @mhaselup, I got it now- 0001 is 1 in decimal. Since the DAC is 4-bit it can get a maximum value of 1111 which is 15 in decimal. So for 1 it produces an output of 0.1v, so for 15 it would produce an output of 0.1*15=1.5. So the full scale output is 1.5v.

Comment: If 0001 (which is 1 bit) produces a voltage of 0.1V, what would 0010 produce?

Comment: What is max value that 4 bits can represent? Multiply that by output for input 0001

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it shows no effort at pointing out areas of confusion and is thus too general

Comment: The questioner left his previous question hanging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a voltage for the smallest step size of the DAC.  That's the voltage for the value 1.

The largest number a 4 bit value can represent is 1111 binary, which is 15 decimal.

Your answer is a simple multiplication product of the voltage for a step size and the number of steps.

---

Just hints since this seems to be homework.